# Null List returning for Multiple Occurrence sections in JAXB

Tags: java, java-8, jaxb

Hi i'm new to JAXB Conversions.

I'm Unmarshalling an xml into java objects. For single occurrence sections there is no issue, but for multiple occurrence not able to map properly. Each time I'm getting null list for multiple occurrence section.

Please suggest me any useful url's or suggest me changes need to be done.

XML ::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<designTheory>
    <Administartor>
        <circuitId>67565675476</circuitId>
        <processId>567855</processId>
        <version>01</version>
        <circuitReferenceValue>ciruit-0001</circuitReferenceValue>
        <property>cal-circuit</property>
    </Administartor>
    <designSec>
        <priloc>priloc</priloc>
        <secloc>secloc</secloc>
        <remarks>remarks field</remarks>
    </designSec>
    <designNotes>
        <notesNumber>1</notesNumber>
        <notes>designNotes 1</notes>
    </designNotes>
    <designNotes>
        <notesNumber>2</notesNumber>
        <notes>designNotes 2</notes>
    </designNotes>
    <designNotes>
        <notesNumber>3</notesNumber>
        <notes>designNotes 3</notes>
    </designNotes>
    <designNotes>
        <notesNumber>4</notesNumber>
        <notes>designNotes 4</notes>
    </designNotes>
</designTheory>
```

Code Snippets are as below :

### DesignTheory.java

```
package org.manjunath.jaxbconversions.beans;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "designTheory")
public class DesignTheory {

    @XmlElement(name = "Administartor", required = true)
    private Administartor admin;

    @XmlElement(name = "designSec", required = true)
    private DesignSec designSec;

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElementRef(name = "designNotes")
    private List<JAXBElement<DesignNotes>> designNotesList;

    public void setAdministartor(Administartor admin){
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    public Administartor getAdministartor() {
        return admin;
    }

    public DesignSec getDesignSec() {
        return designSec;
    }

    public void setDesignSec(DesignSec designSec) {
        this.designSec = designSec;
    }


    public List<JAXBElement<DesignNotes>> getDlrnotes() {
        return designNotesList;
    }

    public void setDlrnotes(List<JAXBElement<DesignNotes>> designNotesList) {
        this.designNotesList = designNotesList;
    }
}
```

### Administartor.java

```
package org.manjunath.jaxbconversions.beans;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Administartor")
public class Administartor {

    @XmlElement(name = "circuitId")
    private String circuitId;

    @XmlElement(name = "processId")
    private String processId;

    @XmlElement(name = "version")
    private String version;

    @XmlElement(name = "circuitReferenceValue")
    private String circuitReferenceValue;

    @XmlElement(name = "property")
    private String property;

    public String getcircuitId() {
        return circuitId;
    }

    public void setcircuitId(String circuitId) {
        this.circuitId = circuitId;
    }

    public String getprocessId() {
        return processId;
    }

    public void setprocessId(String processId) {
        this.processId = processId;
    }

    public String getVer() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVer(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getcircuitReferenceValue() {
        return circuitReferenceValue;
    }

    public void setcircuitReferenceValue(String circuitReferenceValue) {
        this.circuitReferenceValue = circuitReferenceValue;
    }

    public String getproperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setproperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

### DesignSec.java

```
package org.manjunath.jaxbconversions.beans;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "designSec")
public class DesignSec {

    @XmlElement (name = "priloc")
    private String priloc;

    @XmlElement (name = "secloc")
    private String secloc;

    @XmlElement (name = "remarks")
    private String remarks;

    public String getpriloc() {
        return priloc;
    }

    public void setpriloc(String priloc) {
        this.priloc = priloc;
    }

    public String getSecloc() {
        return secloc;
    }

    public void setSecloc(String secloc) {
        this.secloc = secloc;
    }

    public String getremarks() {
        return remarks;
    }

    public void setEcspc(String remarks) {
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }
}
```

### DesignNotes.java

```
package org.manjunath.jaxbconversions.beans;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "designNotes")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DesignNotes {

    @XmlElement (name = "notesNumber")
    private String notesNumber;

    @XmlElement (name = "notes")
    private String notes;

    public String getnotesNumber() {
        return notesNumber;
    }

    public void setnotesNumber(String notesNumber) {
        this.notesNumber = notesNumber;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }
}
```

And I found somewhere the @XmlRegistry and @XmlElementDecl will solve my problem.
But I'm not so good with these annotations, but I tried by using ObjectFactory.java class. No use of this class

### ObjectFactory.java

```
package org.manjunath.jaxbconversions.factory;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.manjunath.jaxbconversions.beans.DesignNotes;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _DesignNotes_QNAME = new QName("designNotes");

    public ObjectFactory(){

    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name="designNotes")
    public JAXBElement<DesignNotes> createDesignNotes(DesignNotes value) {
        return new JAXBElement<DesignNotes>(_DesignNotes_QNAME, DesignNotes.class, value);
    }

}
```

Please suggest me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class `DesignTheory` the definition

```
@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElementRef(name = "designNotes")
private List<JAXBElement<DesignNotes>> designNotesList;
```

is wrong.
In your XML you have

```
<designNotes>
  ...
</desinNotes>
<designNotes>
  ...
</designNotes>
...
```

But you do *not* have an additional wrapper around these `<designNotes>` like this

```
<designNotesList>
  <designNotes>
    ...
  </desinNotes>
  <designNotes>
    ...
  </designNotes>
  ...
<designNotesList>
```

That's why you need to remove the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation.

And you should change its type from `List<JAXBElement<DesignNotes>>`
to `List<DesignNotes>`. So you end up with

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "designNotes")
private List<DesignNotes> designNotesList;
```

Also change the associated getter and setter from `List<JAXBElement<DesignNotes>>`
to `List<DesignNotes>`.

Then you don't need the `ObjectFactory` anymore and can remove it completely.

I verified the corrected classes with your XML and the following test-code

```
@Test
public void testUnmarshall() throws Exception {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(DesignTheory.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    File file = new File("design-theory.xml");
    DesignTheory designTheory = (DesignTheory) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
    Assert.assertNotNull(designTheory.getDlrnotes());
    Assert.assertEquals(4, designTheory.getDlrnotes().size());
}
```

The unmarshalled `designTheory` correctly has a non-null `List<DesignNotes>` with 4 elements.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the code is working fine after modifications.